# Compute the null space of a sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I found the function (null OR nullspace) to find the null space of a regular matrix in R, but I couldn't find any function or package for a sparse matrix (sparseMatrix).

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the code of `ggm::null`, you will see that it is based on the QR decomposition of the input matrix.

On the other hand, the `Matrix` package provides its own method to compute the `QR` decomposition of a sparse matrix.

For example:

```
require(Matrix)
A <- matrix(rep(0:1, 3), 3, 2)
As <- Matrix(A, sparse = TRUE)

qr.Q(qr(A), complete=TRUE)[, 2:3]
qr.Q(qr(As), complete=TRUE)[, 2:3]
```

Comment: Hi Vincent. I used your comment and it was great. Although the matrix and It's transpose are decomposed, But in the sparse case, when the number of rows is less than the number of columns, it does not decompose.
For example:   A<-matrix(1:6, nc=2,nr=3) and
    As <- Matrix(A, sparse= TRUE) and
     > qr.Q(qr(A), complete=TRUE) and
    > qr.Q(qr(As), complete=TRUE) and                            
   > qr.Q(qr(t(A)), complete=TRUE) are working but
  > qr.Q(qr(t(As)), complete=TRUE) dose not work
Error in .local(x, ...) : A must have #{rows} >= #{columns}.  Thanks a lot. Best

Comment: I get the same error message. I have no idea why it works on dense matrices but fails for sparse matrices...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention.